# Add rules to permutations using python?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, rules

since some days I need to create a long list of random strings of lenght 14 that consist of only letters upper and lowercase, non-repeating, so far so good, I'm simply using itertools permutations and printing to a file

```
import itertools    

for coma in itertools.permutations(Alphabet, 14):
    s="".join(coma)
    #write to file code
```

Technical limitations aside (I know this is tons of combinations, space to record them, time it takes, etc, no need to point that out, I know.)

Now I have to add another rule that will help reduce the number of combinations, all strings must have at least 6 uppercase letters and max 8, I have been thinking a lot about how to add this rule because all my ideas require the program to generate the string, check if it meets the criteria, discard if not, but the point is to avoid making combinations that not meet this criteria at all.

Comment: What did you try - edit your code into the question _as text_

Comment: I haven't coded anything yet to set this rule, because all the ideas I had, ended up having the same issue --> The combination is created and then check if the criteria is met, if not, throw away. This will help save space, but not time, which is important in such a huge list. I found a library called more_itertools though that looks interesting and I'm reading it's methods currently.

Comment: What’s wrong with that; is it some actual concrete problem or does it just not feel right even though it works?

Comment: I think I answered that question on my edited comment, doing it that way creates the permutation anyway, and then discards it, but I want to avoid creating them at all to reduce time.

Comment: Nothing concrete then. Password creation can be difficult; good luck.

Comment: I don't get the point of your comment, if you can be clearer I'd appreciate you edit your comment and be more clear on what you are saying, which I guess is something offensive, since you assume I'm doing something that has to do with passwords, I don't know how your comment is supposed to be helpful. Prmutations algorithms have always been a complex problem and adding rules to try to reduce numbers seems to make it even harder instead of simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate lowercase strings, then pick the number and index of letters to be set to uppercase using the `random` module:

```py
import random, string
for i in range(500):
    number_uppercase = random.randint(6,8)
    idx_uppercase = random.sample(range(14), number_uppercase)
    letter_list = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 14)
    for i in idx_uppercase:
        letter_list[i] = letter_list[i].upper()
    s="".join(letter_list)
```

Comment: The idea is good but as I see this method would create a list of random strings which could, in large samples, have dupes, but I need an approach to have permutations of strings, where the order matters, and as an extra rule 6 to 8 letters within this string must be uppercase... I was thinking about making permutations of all lower and all upper of k=7 and merge but that also wont work because all i'll have is half "abcdDEFG" when I need strings like "WsfodTRYliMAaP"

Comment: No quite sure what you mean when you say "the order matters". Duplicates are possible but highly unlikely, so you could add generated values to a `set` object and dump it to a file at the end of the loop without any significant slowdown. Of course, this method is only viable if all generated strings can fit in your RAM.

Comment: To put it into perspective, with the rule you gave, an array of 100 million strings would have a 1/10000 chance of containing a duplicate

Comment: That high @Mike Jack? Lowercase strings without repetitions give you: `26*25*...*(26-14+1) = 26!/12!` possibilities.
Taking uppercase letters into account, we get: `26!/12! * [14C6 + 14C7 + 14C8] ≃ 8e21`.
`100e6/8e21 ≃ 1.25e-14`, so it's a lot more unlikely than a 1/10000 chance.

Comment: While I was wrong, I believe that the actual probability is (14! * (26C6 * 26C8 + 26C7 * 26C7 + 26C8 * 26C6)) ≈ 1e23, barely lower than without the rule 52P14 ≈ 1.5e23. The probability of collision is calculated using the hash collision formula 1 - e^( (-k(k-1)) / (2N) ) . Meaning an array of 100 million strings would actually have a 5 in 100 million probability (5e-8) of collision. While a 10 billion string long array would have a 5 in 10000 chance of a dupe.

Comment: Sorry, now I took a second, third and fourth view on your approach and finally got it. I was missing the part you said I should generate all combinations of letters first, and now I get it, idk what I was thinking, this idea is good. I created a file with all combinations of lowercase, now I will randomly select leters of each string and upper them, and if I want more strings, I can just permute each but now I can separate the job, sorry for my first answer, now I got it !

Comment: No problem, glad you've found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you want all possible permutations with no duplicates then you can try the below code (documented inline)

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

# All possible number of uppers
for i in range(6, 9):
  # All possible permutations of 'n' uppers
  for upper_str in permutations(alphabet, i):
    # All possible permutations of 14-n lowers
    for lower_str in permutations(alphabet, 14-i):
      # format the string
      upper_lower_str = "".join(upper_str).upper()+"".join(lower_str)
      # All possible permutations of the formatted string
      for s in permutations(upper_lower_str, 14):
        print ("".join(s))
```